# VS Code does not recognize unit tests in Flutter

Tags: unit-testing, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter

Visual Studio Code does not recognize unit tests grouped in `group(...)`. But it recognizes unit tests which are not grouped. I mean they are standalone `test(...)`. I want to use group, because I need `setUp()`.

There is `Run | Debug` link above `group`. When I click Debug or Run the Debug console shows `No tests match regular expression "^LocalRepository$".`

The tests are running correctly with `flutter test` command.

Dart SDK: >=2.1.0 <3.0.0

Flutter channel: master

Edit: I found workaround - I just don't use `group` callback. But I can't run all tests by clicking `Run` above `group`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make sure you name you test file ending with `_test.dart` and you will see the run | debug options

Comment: this. is. insane.

Answer (score 12):

I have a Flutter project with two separate test files, both ending in "..._test.dart".

Using the following two test scenarios, one of the files passes, while the second doesn't load and that test fails.

Using launch.json configuration:

```
{
 "name": "Dart: Run all Tests",
 "request": "launch",
 "type": "dart",
 "program": "./test/"
}
```

Using the VS Code menu item `Debug > Start Debugging (F5)`, which I suspicion just uses the above launch.json configuration, yields the same result.

However, using the VS Code menu item `Debug > Start Without Debugging (Ctrl+F5)`, or "flutter test" from the command line, both tests pass.

I suspect this is an internal configuration issue with the VS Code Dart/Flutter extension, as opposed to a problem with Dart/Flutter code structure.

Answer (score 1):

Are your tests/groups spread across multiple files? There are some limitations to the integration between the VS Code extension and the test package that you may be hitting.

There was [a fix](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1460) in v2.23 (released a few days before your question) that should have improved this a little (removing those Run/Debug links in some places they wont' work) but if you're already on that version then maybe it didn't cover your case.

If you can post a small repro [on GitHub](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues) I'd definitely like to see if I can improve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the test has a name different from `''`

Change

```dart
test('', () {
  ...
});
```

to

```dart
test('xxx', () {
  ...
});
```